# HTML5 navigator.online does not work in WebView

Tags: android, html

I am creating a hybrid application by using android and offline html5 pages in android asset. 
navigator.online is not working in Android Webview.

Please help

Comment: By not working, do you mean that it's undefined, or that the behavior is inconsistent? I am having the problem that resembles the latter.

Comment: Hey @mercury, Please accept user1732313's answer.

Comment: see similar question re online status in cordova apps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963780/eventlistener-online-offline-doesnt-work-in-android-cordova-webview)

Comment: see similar question re cordova app online status [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963780/eventlistener-online-offline-doesnt-work-in-android-cordova-webview)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963780/eventlistener-online-offline-doesnt-work-in-android-cordova-webview) is similar and I've posted an answer there that covers this.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is still searching for this one. The solution for me was to register a broadcast receiver in my activity to detect connection change.

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (connectivityChangeReceiver!=null) unregisterReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver,intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver connectivityChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        mWebView.setNetworkAvailable(isNetworkAvailable(context));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you provide below permissions in the `AndroidMenifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to add the following line of code for your events

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
```

make sure you check the values in the functions `function onOnline(){}` & `function onOffline(){}`

Comment: what version of android you are using?

Comment: OS version on android device is 2.3.6 and application built for target version is 2.1

Comment: you might want to have a look at the following link, I am afraid it might not be working for the android version 2.1 , [link](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-froyo-html5-accelerometer-flash-player)

Comment: I have changed the target version from 2.1 to 2.2 or 2.3.1... still finding the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not mistaking the spelling?

it should be navigator.onLine  (camelCase)

Answer (score 0):

Webview is partially supported. Please check browser compatibility in the documentation: [documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine#browser_compatibility)