# EventListener "online" "offline" doesn't work in Android Cordova WebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview, addeventlistener

I have a little problem with Android Cordova Webview. My app doesn't trigger the eventListener "online/offline".

I try many types of listeners:

```
window.addEventListener('online', function() {alert('ON LISTENER');});
document.addEventListener('online', function() {alert('ON LISTENER');});
$(window).on("online", function() {alert('ON LISTENER');});
```

but none work in android webview

Comment: Did you find anythin?

Comment: do you have some logs to share from device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "onLine" means connected to "a network" as opposed to "the internet".

Tested using
5th gen Amazon Fire - Android 5.1.1 lollipop, 
Nook HD - Android 4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich and 
Samsung galaxy S3 Neo - Android 4.4.2 KitKat

Found the standard browser events and properties unreliable but this seems to work reliably ;

[cordova network information plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

eg. after deviceReady you can call this ;

```
function isOnLine(){
    return navigator.connection.type !== Connection.NONE ; 
}
```

or register these ;

```
window.addEventListener("online",someFunction);
window.addEventListener("offline",someFunction);
```

all work as expected except perhaps that the (correct) online/offline event fires on startup.

---

In comparison what I found using the standard browser events and properties ...

mostly using a 5th gen Amazon Fire - Android 5.1.1 lollipop;

`navigator.onLine` starts out as false which may be incorrect ( and is read only ).

If, when started, device was connected and..
    device subsequently disconnected - `navigator.onLine` = false....
    device subsequently connected - `navigator.onLine` = true.

If, when started, device was disconnected and...
    device subsequently connected - `navigator.onLine` = true....
    device subsequently disconnected - `navigator.onLine` = false.

Thereafter `navigator.onLine` reflects device connection status changes....sometimes.

So, it starts as false (which may be incorrect) and is then set (unreliably) when the device state next changes.

```
window.addEventListener("online",online.bind(this));
```

and

```
window.addEventListener("offline",offline.bind(this));
```

never fired ( seen on Nook also ).

```
window.ononline = function(){console.log("online");}
```

and

```
window.onoffline = function(){console.log("offline");}
```

both fired but unreliably and depending on where in the device the wifi was toggled... so the plugin appears to be the only solution for Cordova apps for now.